# Linking D3.js line charts with Leaflet map path on mousemove

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

I am trying to link the connected line-charts of [this](http://bl.ocks.org/oikonang/acada278346a3df9da1b870be181f55a) (I built it on bl.ocks instead of jsfiddle because it didn't let me include http links) with the polyline of the leaflet map so as while on mouse-move on the line-charts, to have a similar functionality on the path on map. Can you please suggest of something? Or have seen something similar that I can be inspired from?

Thank you.

Comment: Check [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868) by mbostock.

Comment: @Camilo I know how to create a moving point on a line. What I don't know is if I am able to access the svg of each polyline created by the leaflet api and add a circle according to the coordinates matched by the mousemove function.

Comment: What I do is to assign a class on leaflet element creation, either `onEachFeature` or `.append()` when I'm using D3 to draw the elements on map, then it's easy to use a D3 selector (check the code in this [example](https://cccruzr.github.io/colmigrationmapbox/)). You can also create a `circleMarker` ([link](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#circlemarker)) at the specific location you need, giving a `className`.